# Remote Service - Unable to start service Intent U=0 not found

Tags: android, service

У меня есть сервис

## Manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".SocketService"
    android:process=":socket"/>
```

Я подключаюсь к нему через `bindService`
и использую `AIDL`

Сервис предназначен для обмена данными с сервером и приложением. Сервис не имеет интент-фильтров.

```
public final class SocketService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new Binder();
    }
    private final class Binder extends ISocketService.Stub {
        @Override
        public void on(String event, ISocketEmitterListener listener) throws RemoteException {
            ...
        }
        @Override
        public int emit(String event, byte[] bytes) throws RemoteException {
            ...
            return 0;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        boolean stopSelf = DBManager.getBoolean(DBManager.SOCKET_SERVICE_STOP_SELF);
        if (stopSelf) {
            stopSelf();
            DBManager.save(DBManager.SOCKET_SERVICE_STOP_SELF, false);
        }
        Timber.i("SocketService unbinded!");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Timber.i("SocketService started!");
        ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        stopSelf();
        Timber.i("SocketService task removed!");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        DBManager.save(DBManager.SOCKET_SERVICE_IS_RUNNING, false);
        Timber.i("SocketService destroyed!");
    }
}
```

Моя проблема в том, что когда приложение получает какую-либо ошибку и вылетает, или просто некорректно закрывается, например выгружается пользователем через диспетчер задач, то следующий запуск службы уже невозможен! Для этого нужно переустановить приложение, иначе пишет это:
`ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=package.name/.SocketService} U=0: not found`

Как избавиться от этого **БЕЗ ПЕРЕУСТАНОВКИ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ** ?

Я уже перепробовал много способов:
1) Переопределить `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` и сделать там `undind` и `stopService` сервиса перед `System.exit(1)`
2) Ovveride `onTaskRemoved()` с `stopSelf()` внутри
3) Итд...

Сейчас я сделал такой вот метод для проверки, чтобы если что сообщить юзеру, что он должен переустановить приложение из-за этой ошибки.

```
public static boolean checkOnNonNull(Context context, Class<?> clazz) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, clazz);
    ResolveInfo rInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveService(service, PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);
    ServiceInfo sInfo = rInfo != null ? rInfo.serviceInfo : null;
    if (sInfo == null) {
        Timber.e("Unable to start service " + service + ": not found");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

***UPD***
Я провел некоторые тесты и получается как будто реально пропадает запись из манифеста, потому что я начал прибавлять цифры к названию класса и сервис начинал работать с уже новым именем. Но все старые имена были not found.

```
<service
    android:name=".SocketService+[1-10]"
    android:process=":socket"/>
// Затем я подставлял цифры в обратном порядке и .SocketService9 будучи использованным один раз уже not found.
```

Comment: я прочитал про похожую проблему, которая более близка к моей https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780049/in-what-case-does-bindservice-return-false/17781118#17781118

Comment: Вашему сервису обязательно нужен отдельный процесс (`android:process=":socket"`)? Заглянув на en-SO по этой проблеме - причин может быть вагон. Поэтому давайте больше подробностей. Сервис биндится внутри приложения или из вне, манифест не помешает показать (хотя бы в общих чертах), как и где происходит вызов сервиса?

Comment: android:process=":socket" — да это оябзательно, потому что этот сервис юзают само приложение и еще один сервис который тоже в другом процессе. И этот сервис должен жить независимо от жизни того или другого. В манифесте абсолютно ничего особенного нет. Сервис биндиться и самом приложении и в еще одном сервисе. Если тот или другой завершаются то в onUnbind ставится stopSelf() чтобы если другой клиент еще жив смог его юзать. Ну это из маны, все логично.

Comment: Причем если приложение запущено и поверх устанавливается новая версия, то проиходит таже самая ошибка. Тоже самое и при разработке в AS, билдю проект на реальный девайс, и если он остается запущенным и я делаю следующий билд, то сервис уже not found. Получается как будто он у меня не прописан в манифесте, но по факту он прописан! но после любого вылета он как-будто исчезает из манифеста...

Answer (score 0):

Едиственным рабочим вариантом когда сервис отключается как компонент оказалось его ручное включение:

```
public static boolean checkOnNonNull(Context context, Class<?> clazz) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, clazz);
    ResolveInfo rInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveService(service, PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);
    ServiceInfo sInfo = rInfo != null ? rInfo.serviceInfo : null;
    if (sInfo == null) {
        Timber.e("Unable to start service " + service + ": not found");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (!checkOnNonNull(context, MyServiceClass.class)) {
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyServiceClass.class.getName());
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
}
```